# Dynamic attribute/property in lit-element at html level component

Tags: javascript, lit-element

How could you pass a dynamic attribute to a lit-element component at html page. e.g.

my-element.js

```
class MyElement extends LitElement {

static get properties() {
    return {    myProp : { type : Object } };
}

render() {
   return html`${this.myProp}`;

}
}
```

index.html

```
<script>
var comp = { "name": "Alice", "place" : "wonderland" }
</script>

<my-element myProp=${comp}></my-element>
```

Now I am having issue that this value is not getting reflected however if I pass a static string of the object then it takes it. what if I need a component at root level with dynamic attribute being changed by another function or something.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the value as an attribute, and these are always converted to strings.

Instead use `.property` notation:

```
const comp = { name: "Alice", place : "wonderland" }

html`<my-element .myProp=${comp}></my-element>`;
```

If you want to be able to pass the value from plain HTML use `JSON.stringify` to searialise the object to the string and in `MyElement` use `JSON.parse` to convert it back.